# Jolt Transform to get below output

Tags: java, json, jolt

I want to write a jolt transformation to get the below output

Input

```json
{
  "payload": {
    "header": {
      "abc": "demo",
      "def": "demo1"
    },
    "payload": {
      "qwer": "asdf",
      "zxcv": "uiop"
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```json
{
  "header": {
    "abc": "demo",
    "def": "demo1"
  },
  "payload": {
    "qwer": "asdf",
    "zxcv": "uiop"
  }
}
```

can this be achieved in jolt

Comment: Can you check out the shortest one provided as the third answer please

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can achieve the expected output using jolt.

Here is the Jolt spec to get the expected output.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the **Jolt transformation** spec to achieve the desired output:

JSON

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "header": "@(1,header)",
        "payload": "@(1,payload)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it in a shortest way by using the following spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "" // the whole value of the payload with no reflection
    }
  }
]
```